# data validation between microservices

Tags: node.js, rest, design-patterns, microservices

Lets say i have 3 micro-services `books`, `authors`, `attachments`.

Author wants to add cover image for book

1. Once author select image from gallery, file gets uploaded in attachments service with author-id(user-id) which return some metadata such us `{id: 1}`.
2. Second API will associate attachment to book like follow.

```
PUT /books/1/cover-image
payload: {id: 1}
```

Now Book service has to validate the following

1. Attachment with id `1` exists or not.
2. If exists it should verify current author(user) is owner of the attachment.

Approach 1:

1. Create API endpoint in attachment service to which return `{id: 1, authorId: 1}` then i can verify the attachment metadata. but it end-up in one more API call(round trip).

Approach 2

1. Once the user upload the image, instead of returning attachment id in  metadata such us `{id: 1}`  return signed id `{id: sign(authorId, attachmentId, secret)}`.
2. Book review have same `secret` where it can decode and verify attachment-id and author-id which avoid multiple API calls.

Is there any cons with approach 2?

Answer (score 1):

> Now Book service has to validate the following
>
> - Attachment with id 1 exists or not.
> - If exists it should verify current author(user) is owner of the attachment.

You are very correct in those two points but I want you to think what service should own them.
The fact that an attachment with `id=1` exists is a responsibility of `attachments` service, so you need to do an API call to make sure the response isn't `404`.

However current author verification should happen in the books service since it is happening for book update action. So what I think the right approach is to have `author_id` stored in the `attachments` service so when you query an attachment by id it returns not only that the record exists but also an id of an author. To put it simply
`GET /attachments/1`
returns`{id: 1, author_id: 1}`.

Then when author does `PUT /books/1/cover-image` you probably would extract the `author id` from the token and can validate that this `id` is equivalent to the `author_id` from `attachments` service which is essentially what you want to verify.

Comment: i have updated the question, instead using API call to verify asset exists, can we use some `signing` algorithm is my question.